# Query to search all packages where a particular lookup is used

Tags: oracle

Is there a query I can run to search all packages to see if a particular lookup type is used in any of the packages?
There are too many packages to open each one and do a find on the value(s) I'm looking for.

Comment: What do you mean by a "particular lookup"?

Comment: particular lookup type means suppose I have created lookuptype as 'ABC', now I want to find this ABC is used in which packages. Hope I am clear now

Comment: what is a 'lookuptype'? Is it some kind of a custom type?

Answer (score 0):

You can use all_source or dba_source if you have access to it.

```
select * 
from all_source
where text like '%your value here%'
```

Comment: Small improvement:
select * 
from all_source
where UPPER(text) like '%YOUR VALUE HERE%';
It's better use uppercase/lowercase :)

Comment: Hi,No I could not find .

Comment: Try to find something you are sure that it is there.

Comment: I am trying with the one I am sure of its presence,but not getting the details

Comment: I think all_source only shows you packages where you have permissions, maybe try dba_source?  (keep the upper() part)